# C fread char Codeblocks

Tags: c, char, codeblocks, fread

i'm trying to run a simple program with Codeblocks 16.11. I get stuck trying to read a char from a file in the following code...

```
FILE *fo;
FILE *ft;
char c;

if ((fo = fopen("mayus.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        perror("opening mayus");
    }

int m;
m= fread(c, 1, 1, fo);
printf("I just read for the first time with result m = %d\n",m);
```

my file mayus.txt its just a txt with "AbCDEFGHIjK" wrote inside. I'm expecting to see a printf with m=1, but i keep getting m=0 in the console.

Comment: Note that `perror()` reports an error but does return.  If there is an error opening the file, your code continues to use the unopened file handle.  This would not be good for the health of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check the `fread` prototype:

`size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`

and so `m= fread(c, 1, 1, fo);` is wrong

What you need is

```
m = fread(&c, 1, 1, fo);  // the first param should be a pointer to the buffer
```

Comment: You're totally right. Such a simple mistake. Thank you very much"